# Keep jQuery UI Accordion content active based on navigation decisions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-accordion, submenu

I have a navigational menu that uses the jQuery UI accordion. I have a script that says apply class style active to the li a.

```
            $(".secondaryMenu a").each(function() {   
                if (this.href == window.location.href) {
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                    }
                    });
```

I want to say any accordion panel that has this class applied then content panel stay active on that page, that way a user clicks on the link and goes to another page the panel will stay active with the navigation visible. Because I did not need to place the pages in different directories I was hoping I could just use the the active class because if a user clicks on it then that is the page and section they will be under anyways.

Markup:

```
            <nav>
            <ul id="accordion3">
             <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                <li class="accHeader"><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                <li class="accHeader"><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
                <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
             <li class="accHeader"><a href="somewhere.php">Link/a></li>
                 <ul>
                 <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="somewhere.php">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
        $(function() {
                  $( "#accordion3" ).accordion({
                    navigation: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    heightStyle: "content",
                    header:'.accHeader',
                    icons:  {header: 'acc-plus', activeHeader: 'acc-minus', },
                    active: $("#accordion3 .accHeader ul li a").hasClass('active')
                                });
                                      $("#accordion3 li a").click(function() {
                    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
               return false;

              });
```

My question, how can I accomplish the content panel to be active based off if any of the links under the header has the active class applied?

I can think about how to do it, but not really accomplish it. Look for active class applied to link under header if true then keep content active. If false default should be active false.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's parents selector to find the parent and apply the class.

```
$(".secondaryMenu a").each(function() {   
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active").parents(".accHeader").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I do, then that should work.

Comment: I am trying to have the content under the header stay visible instead of collapse based off it there is a link in the content that has the class active.